# Why obj is not iterable

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

While compiling this code I am getting an error that obj is not iterable. Why? I have to check how many users are online

```
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function countOnline(obj) {
  let num =0;
  for(let user of obj){
    if(user['online']==true){
      num++;
    }
  }
  return num;
}

console.log(countOnline(users));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

`for...of` is used for looping over [*iterable objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) while `for...in` iterates over the enumerable properties of an object. For `for...of` to work, the object must implement the [`@@iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) method (Array, string, Set etc)

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function countOnline(obj) {
  let num = 0;
  for (let user in obj) {
    if (obj[user]['online'] == true) {
      num++;
    }
  }
  return num;
}

console.log(countOnline(users));
```

In `for...in`, the `user` variable will represent key of the object like `Alan`. So, to get the value of the property, you need to do use `obj[user]` (eg: `obj["Alan"]`). So, the condition will be changed to:

```
if (obj[user]['online'] == true)
```

Comment: But even after using in rather than on num is returning to be 0.

Comment: @AdityaLamba you also need to change the condition to `obj[user]['online']`

Comment: @AdityaLamba I have added the explanation belwo snippet. `user` will be the key name like `"Alan"`, `"Jeff"`. There is no `online` property in a string. `obj[user]` will get the value for the `"Alan"` key

Answer (score 0):

Objects don't have the `@@iterator` symbol by default , to use `for..of` you'll need to add it to the object :

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

users[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
  for (value of Object.values(this)) {
    yield value;
  }
};

for (let user of users) {
  console.log(user)
}
```

Or use `for..of` with `Object.entries` ( or `Object.values` )

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: false
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(users)) {
  console.log('key :', key, 'value : ', value)
}

console.log('***********');

for (let user of Object.values(users)) {
  console.log({user})
}
```